# Can't install SSL on Anaconda Environment

Tags: python, ssl, anaconda

(cv_app_1) D:\Perkuliahan\semester_5\MBKM 2023\AIM0605D2203 Deploying Computer Vision\app>pip install ssl
Collecting ssl
Using cached ssl-1.16.tar.gz (33 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [27 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 14, in 
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\cv_app_1\lib\site-packages\setuptools_*init*_.py", line 266, in 
monkey.patch_all()
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\cv_app_1\lib\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 98, in patch_all
patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\cv_app_1\lib\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 165, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
patch_func(*msvc14('*get_vc_env'))
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\cv_app_1\lib\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 155, in patch_params
mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\cv_app_1\lib\importlib_*init**.py", line 127, in import_module
return *bootstrap.*gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\cv_app_1\lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 20, in 
import unittest.mock as mock
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\cv_app_1\lib\unittest_*init**.py", line 60, in 
from .async_case import IsolatedAsyncioTestCase
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\cv_app_1\lib\unittest\async_case.py", line 1, in 
import asyncio
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\cv_app_1\lib\asyncio_*init**.py", line 8, in 
from .base_events import *
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\cv_app_1\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 34, in 
import ssl
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wufzpgdb\ssl_fab7e432775b4ab399def494f22622c4\ssl_*init*_.py", line 140
except SSLError, x:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I have tried various ways to install this, but I can't find the right way

Comment: does SSL work on windows ?  i use different methods to connect.